# Initializing an infinite number of char **

Tags: c, char, malloc

I'm making a raytracing engine in C using the minilibX library.
I want to be able to read in a `.conf` file the configuration for the scene to display:

For example:

```
(Az@Az 117)cat universe.conf
#randomcomment
obj:eye:x:y:z
light:sun:100
light:moon:test
```

The number of objects can vary between 1 and the infinite.
From now on, I'm reading the file, copying each line 1 by 1 in a char **tab, and mallocing by the number of objects found, like this:

```
void    open_file(int fd, struct s_img *m)
{
  int   i;
  char  *s;
  int   curs_obj;
  int   curs_light;

  i = 0;
  curs_light = 0;
  curs_obj = 0;
  while (s = get_next_line(fd))
    {
      i = i + 1;
      if (s[0] == 'l')
        {
          m->lights[curs_light] = s;
          curs_light = curs_light + 1;
         }
       else if (s[0] == 'o')
         {
           m->objs[curs_obj] = s;
           curs_obj = curs_obj + 1;
         }
       else if (s[0] != '#')
         {
          show_error(i, s);
          stop_parsing(m);
         }
  }
```

Now, I want to be able to store each information of each `tab[i]` in a new `char **tab`, 1 for each object, using the `':'` as a separation.
So I need to initialize and `malloc` an undetermined number of `char **tab`. How can I do that?

(Ps: I hope my code and my english are good enough for you to understand. And I'm using only the very basic function, like read, write, open, malloc... and I'm re-building everything else, like printf, get_line, and so on)

Comment: Whats wrong with allocating new space as you need it?

Comment: I need to allocate a new char **tab for each new object. So, How do I do this?

Is there a way to declare as much char **tab as I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an alternative approach (as this is c, not c++) and allocate simply large buffers as we go by:

```
char *my_malloc(size_t n) {
      static size_t space_left = 0;
      static char *base = NULL;
      if (base==NULL || space_left < n) base=malloc(space_left=BIG_N);
      base +=n; return base-n;
}
```

Disclaimer: I've omitted the garbage collection stuff and testing return values and all safety measures to keep the routine short.

Another way to think this is to read the file in to a large enough mallocated array (you can check it with ftell), scan the buffer, replace delimiters, line feeds etc. with ascii zero characters and remember the starting locations of keywords.

Comment: The Ftell option seems to be good so...
I'm going to recode ftell, then try with this. Thanks!

Comment: You obviously got that it's `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); sz=ftell(fp);` and that it's non portable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't allocate an *indeterminate* amount of memory; `malloc` doesn't support it. What you can do is to allocate enough memory *for now* and revise that later:

```
size_t buffer = 10;
char **tab = malloc(buffer);

//...
if (indexOfObjectToCreate > buffer) {
  buffer *= 2;
  tab = realloc(tab, buffer);
}
```

Comment: For anyone who won't realize this: you'll also have to watch out for integer overflow.  buffer has a maximum size, and if you're truly reading in an "infinite" amount of data, you'll eventually run out (thought this is less important on a 64bit system than a smaller one).